# Can't install SSL cerificate - error AH00169 SIGTERM

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, listener

I'm new to server stuff. On Azure I run VirtualMachnine based on Ubuntu 14. I install apache2 and everything workd fine.

Now I need to add SSL certificate. So at default-ssl.conf I write:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomainname.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomainname.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mydomainname.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mydomainname.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

on laravel.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Now I have in portf.conf :

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

and I get error when I try to enter address with **https://**  :

```
[Tue May 10 13:52:22.215535 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4063] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue May 10 13:52:23.304933 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4217] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_gnutls/0.5.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 10 13:52:23.304992 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4217] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

4 days I cant solve this problem. Please help.

What is a problem here?

Comment: maybe to change ssl module with mod_gnutls

Comment: I don't really see why would you want to use `if`.

Comment: so what to use ?

Comment: Nothing, just set up a `VirtualHost` for http and another for https.

Comment: so to delete <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 ?

Comment: AGAIN DONT WORK SSL

Comment: You didn't add a password to the key, right?

Comment: yes I add password to key...

Comment: I add password and with that generated key I buy SSL, from ssl provider (COMODO) I gte .crt file

Comment: Apache server needs to access that password to run, if it has a password, he cannot do it.

Comment: but in ssh console apache dont ask me for password ...

Comment: Don't make this a chat box, I already said why it's not working, google some info and fix it, you now know what the problem is.

Comment: no, its not password problem